# Fit image to container by its smaller side without knowing the orientation of the image

Tags: html, css, image, responsive

I have a container (for example a square) with given abolute size.
Now I would like to fit an image inside of the container to its parent container by its smaller side , whereas the larger side overflows the container.
In other words: the smaller side should exactly match 100%, but both should be >= 100% of the container. This all without squeezing the image.

It should work independent of the image orientation being landscape or portrait because I would like to cover both cases without knowing which orientation the image has.

Is it possible to solve it by saying the min-width and min-height of the image is equal to the height and width to the parent container? Or anyone has any other simple solution?

Appreciate any hint
Thanks, Sebastian

Comment: you have to use **object-fit: cover;** or else **overflow: hidden**.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible using only CSS, but it's [not supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit) cross-browser. Hello, IE:

```css
img {
  object-fit: cover;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

See it working:

```css
.sized-container {
  width: 25vw;
  height: 25vw;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
.sized-container img {
  object-fit: cover;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {margin :0;}
```

```html
<div class="sized-container">
  <img src="https://loremflickr.com/640/360">
</div>
<div class="sized-container">
  <img src="https://loremflickr.com/360/640">
</div>
<div class="sized-container">
  <img src="https://loremflickr.com/100/100">
</div>
<div class="sized-container">
  <img src="https://loremflickr.com/1000/1000">
</div>
```

---

For a cross-browser solution, you have to rely on JavaScript.
Hide the `<img>` elements while grabbing their `src` values to set the container backgrounds. The containers have `background-size:cover` to provide the exact sizing and cropping behavior you are looking for.
The solution also enlarges small images to fit the width/height of sized parent:

```js
let containers = document.querySelectorAll('.sized-container');
for (let i = 0; i < containers.length; i++) {
  var container = containers[i],
      image = container.querySelector('img');
  if (image)
    container.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + image.getAttribute('src') + ')'
}
```

```css
.sized-container {
  width: 25vw;
  height: 25vw;
  background: transparent 50% 50% no-repeat /cover;
  float: left;
}
.sized-container img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
}
body { margin: 0;}
```

```html
<div class="sized-container">
  <img src="https://loremflickr.com/640/360">
</div>
<div class="sized-container">
  <img src="https://loremflickr.com/360/640">
</div>
<div class="sized-container">
  <img src="https://loremflickr.com/100/100">
</div>
<div class="sized-container">
  <img src="https://loremflickr.com/1000/1000">
</div>
```

If using jQuery, the script would be a bit shorter:

```js
$('.sized-container').each((i,e) => {
  let img = $('img', e);
  if (img.is('img'))
    $(e).css({backgroundImage:'url(' + img.first().attr('src') + ')'});
})
```

**Important note:** Obviously, if you have control over markup, you should set the `background-image` of the parent when you're generating the markup, so you wouldn't have to grab it from images using JavaScript. However, I'd leave the `<img>` elements in, still hidden, for accessibility purposes (think screen readers, title attributes, etc...).

Comment: Thank you very much Andrei for the super fast response and the nice solution using javascript! I really appreciate your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to show the image as a background image. The downside is that the image will not behave exactly like the `<img>` tag.

You can use the following CSS on a `<div>` or something similar:

```
height: [HEIGHT] px;
width: [WIDTH] px;
background-image: url('[URL]');
background-size: cover;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast answer and suggested solution!